# Error in BindJndiForEJBNonMessageBinding using ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml

Tags: deployment, ejb, websphere

Deploying an application in WAS 8 gives me an error:
Cannot find a match for supplied option: "[ejb.jar, ejbName, ejb.jar,META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml, ejb/ejbName]" for task "BindJndiForEJBNonMessageBinding"

my entry in ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml
`<session name="ejbName">
    <interface class="com.manager.EJBNameManager" binding-name="ejb/ejbName"/></session>`

my entry in deploy.jacl
`[-BindJndiForEJBNonMessageBinding ejb.jar ejbName ejb.jar,META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml ejb/ejbName]`

my ejb.jar structure has META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml also.

Was my entry in ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml correct? Please enlighten me on this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of providing the path to your ejb jar bindings (`ejb.jar,META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml`), you should be providing the path to your ejb deployment descriptor (e.g. `ejb.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml`).

In addition, you shouldn't even need the ejb bindings file, because you are creating the binding using JACL. The `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file will automatically be created for you as a result of your deployment.

(Also, as a side note, WAS deprecated its use of JACL in WAS 7, so you should consider using `jython` for your `wsadmin` scripts instead.)

Comment: Thanks Shelley. I modified the ibm-ejb-jar.bnd.xml and ejb-jar.xml. ejb-jar.xml only contains the ejb-name and ejb-class while ibm-ejb-jar-bnd has the EJB and Resource references. I also used JACL to bind the JNDI names. I didn't used jyton for this but if time permits, I might try to use it instead. Thanks again.